# Intrinsic oscillation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oscillators, adiabatic

In this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01082)
It defines some time scales.in page 3 was said that
$$
\tau_E^{-1}\equiv min |\epsilon_{mn}(t)| \quad ,m \neq n
$$

where $ \epsilon_{mn}(t) ≡ \epsilon_m(t) − \epsilon_n(t)$ denotes the instantaneous
energy gap. Hence, $\tau_E(t)$ also corresponds to the **longest
timescale of the intrinsic oscillation period in the off-
diagonal density matrix elements**.
Can any one explain the part that is bold ?I can’t understand this part.